# Powershell runs script from previous edit

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

I am practicing Powershell in VSCode.
I have noticed that when I hit F5 to run my script, Powershell runs the previous version of the script (before my changes). I am definitely saving the file after my edits.
So, for example, I might change the text in this line:

```
Add-Content -Path "D:\Text_File.txt" -value "$_ - MP3 File count is: $Cnt"
```

But it will continue to show the same output until I run it a second time.

This is the script I am using in case it is relevant:

```
Param(
    [string]$Path = 'D:\WMA - BU of wma music files',
    [string]$DestinationPath = "D:\WMA-Only",
    [string]$OutputFileDest = "D:\Text_File.txt"
)

$MainDirList = Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Directory | ForEach-Object {$_.FullName}

$MainDirList | Out-File -FilePath D:\Text_File.txt

$MainDirList | WriteFolder

function WriteFolder
{
    process 
    {
        $FilteredList = Get-ChildItem -Path $_ -Force -Recurse -Filter "*.mp3"
        
        $Cnt = $FilteredList.count
        Add-Content -Path "D:\Text_File.txt" -value "$_ - MP3 File count is: $Cnt"
    }
}
```

Visual Studio code version is 1.62.2
Powershell extension is v2021.10.2

I am wondering if I am meant to clear variables or the like at the end of a script?
I am viewing the output in the latest version of notepad++

Comment: Could it be because you've defined one function inside another function? Normally when you run a script, it finds any Functions and pre-processes them before running the script. But in your case, it only processes the outer function, which only creates the inner function when it's run.

Comment: @SteveTaylor, worth looking at. Thanks for the lead. I'll see.

Comment: I've added that as an Answer in case it is helpful - normally best practice is to describe all Functions in the header of your script, or as a separate module (*.psm1) which your script loads.

Comment: I played with this idea but I have not resolved the issue. I put the function into a different file and at first I was getting the same behaviour. I removed the 'process' block and once again, the output was not updated but then, the output did not get updated after multiple attempts. So clearly the function gets stored somewhere.

Comment: oh, if you're now storing the function externally that's a slightly different problem - if you've already loaded it from the other file (perhaps via `Import-Module`) you'll have to apply the `-Force` argument from the second run onwards to ensure it overwrites the stored script. `Import-Module $myModule -Force`

Comment: @SteveTaylor, I have found I need to run the function for it to be registered, which I imagine is something along the lines of what you are describing. That explains the previous behaviour too. When it was on the same page, the function gets 'registered?' on the first run and then is ready to go on the second. 

It's not the kind of behaviour I am used to. I need to do more reading it seems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be because you've defined one function inside another function? Normally when you run a script, it finds any Functions and pre-processes them before running the script. But in your case, it only processes the outer function, which only creates the inner function when it's run.

I'm not sure what your parent function is called, but you could try just having the two functions side-by-side:

```
Function myFunction{
    Param(
        [string]$Path = 'D:\WMA - BU of wma music files',
        [string]$DestinationPath = "D:\WMA-Only",
        [string]$OutputFileDest = "D:\Text_File.txt"
    )
    Process{
        $MainDirList = Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Directory | ForEach-Object {$_.FullName}
        $MainDirList | Out-File -FilePath D:\Text_File.txt
        $MainDirList | WriteFolder
    }
}



function WriteFolder
{
    process 
    {
        $FilteredList = Get-ChildItem -Path $_ -Force -Recurse -Filter "*.mp3"
        
        $Cnt = $FilteredList.count
        Add-Content -Path "D:\Text_File.txt" -value "$_ - MP3 File count is: $Cnt"
    }
}
```

Or else you could move the WriteFolder function into its own Powershell module (*.psm1) and load it in your main script:

```
Import-Module "WriteFolder.psm1" -Force
```

The `-Force` parameter is optional, but if you're regularly changing the module file you'll need it to ensure the updates are loaded, rather than just caching the old version of the module.

Comment: I didn't actually have the original script in a function. I was going to make it into one, hence the 'param' specifications but hadn't gotten to that point. When I removed the 'param' block, it still behaved the same. 
I guess one solution is to run the edited function separately so it gets registered? 
I can't say this is the answer but you definitely put me on the right track. thanks. Can you edit this to reflect your comments from above and I will mark it as answered?

Comment: @dra_red - Sure thing - I've updated the answer to present both options - just having the Functions side by side, or loading the second one from a separate module as you're doing now. Is that capturing everything you wanted to see?

Comment: @SteveTaylor, would putting `function WriteFolder` before `function MyFunction` make any difference?

Comment: @lit - Honestly, they should both be perfectly happy so long as they are both at the base level of the script. When the script runs, it should load *all* functions it finds at the immediate base level before it actually runs any other line of code. The original problem was the second function being *inside* the first, not the order they come in. Though best practice would state that you should declare all Functions at the *top* of your script for consistency's sake.